# Rails merge multiple json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, hash, merge

Can anyone help me with this problem?

So, here is the problem, I want to merge this query response:

```
 @energy = Alert.where(["alert_type = ?", "Energy"]).last.as_json

 @cost = Alert.where(["alert_type = ?", "Cost"]).last.as_json
```

Then I merge those object with:

```
@current_notif = @energy.merge(@cost)
```

But those just give me `@cost` object like this:

```
{
  "alert_type": "Cost",
  "value": 30000000,
  "status": "Cost exceeds limit",
  "created_at": "2017-06-03T15:31:21.156+07:00",
  "updated_at": "2017-06-03T15:31:21.156+07:00",
  "home_id": 2
}
```

Rather than a merged `@energy + @cost` like this:

```
    { {"alert_type": "Energy",
       "value": 384455.813978742,
       "status": "Energy too high",
       "created_at": "2017-05-31T11:31:12.907+07:00",
       "updated_at": "2017-05-31T11:31:12.907+07:00",
       "home_id": 2 },
     {
       "alert_type": "Cost",
       "value": 30000000,
       "status": "Cost exceeds limit",
       "created_at": "2017-06-03T15:31:21.156+07:00",
       "updated_at": "2017-06-03T15:31:21.156+07:00",
       "home_id": 2
     }
}
```

Comment: According to your example you want to receive an array, rather than a hash.

Comment: `.merge` is behaving the way it is supposed to. Read the docs: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge. Also, that resulting hash isn't a valid hash. Are you sure you don't want an `array`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want you could "join" both values, and then over that use `as_json`:

```
[@energy, @cost].as_json
# [{"alert_type": "Energy", ... }, {"alert_type": "Cost", ... }]
```

Or if you want you could use the `IN` expression, in order to deal with ActiveRecord instead having to customize the result this gives you:

```
Alert.where(alert_type: ['Energy', 'Cost']).as_json
# [{"alert_type": "Energy", ... }, {"alert_type": "Cost", ... }]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because that's how merge works.

```
hash = {:name => "Ade", :gender => "Male"}.merge(:name => "Bob") 
puts hash # {:name=>"Bob", :gender=>"Male"}
```

Solution:

```
results = [ @energy, @cost ]
results.each do |result|
  puts result['alert_type'] # Energy, Cost 
end
```